# LP Staking solidity contract : what rewardRate should i set?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

So i'm looking for a staking contract exemple to understand and deploy for my token

I found the same logic repeating in most of the contracts which is the sythetix staking algorithm

The calculation is very clever and hard to understand,

here's the code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8;

// Hero Prime Staking v1.0

contract StakingRewards {
    IERC20 public stakingToken;
    IERC20 public rewardsToken;
    
    uint public rewardRate = 100;
    uint public lastUpdateTime;
    uint public rewardPerTokenStored;
    uint public lockedTime = 120; // 2 Min
    // uint public lockedTime = 1209600; // 14 days
    uint public initialTime = 60; // 1 Min
    // uint public initialTime = 604800; // 7 days
    
    address public owner;
    
    bool public isAvailable = true;
    
    mapping(address => uint) public userRewardPerTokenPaid;
    mapping(address => uint) public rewards;
    mapping(address => uint) public stakeStart;

    uint public _totalSupply;
    mapping(address => uint) public _balances;
    
    
    event StartStaked(address indexed owner, uint _amount, uint _time);
    event WitdrawStaked(address indexed owner, uint _amount, uint _time, bool _withPenalty);
    event WitdrawRewards(address indexed owner, uint _amount, uint _time, bool _withPenalty);
    
    
    constructor(address _stakingToken, address _rewardsToken) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        stakingToken = IERC20(_stakingToken);
        rewardsToken = IERC20(_rewardsToken);
    }
    
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    
    function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) external onlyOwner{
        owner = _newOwner;
    }
    function pause() public onlyOwner{
        isAvailable = false;
    }
    function unpause() public onlyOwner{
        isAvailable = true;
    }
    
    function rewardPerToken() public view returns (uint) {
        if (_totalSupply == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return
            rewardPerTokenStored +
            (((block.timestamp - lastUpdateTime) * rewardRate * 1e18) / _totalSupply);
    }

    function earned(address account) public view returns (uint) {
        return
            ((_balances[account] *
                (rewardPerToken() - userRewardPerTokenPaid[account])) / 1e18) +
            rewards[account];
    }
    
    modifier updateReward(address account) {
        rewardPerTokenStored = rewardPerToken();
        lastUpdateTime = block.timestamp;

        rewards[account] = earned(account);
        userRewardPerTokenPaid[account] = rewardPerTokenStored;
        _;
    }
    
    function changeRate(uint _newRate) public onlyOwner{
        rewardRate = _newRate;
    }
    
    function stake(uint _amount) external updateReward(msg.sender) {
        require(isAvailable == true, "The Staking is Paused");
        _totalSupply += _amount;
        _balances[msg.sender] += _amount;
        stakeStart[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
        stakingToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
        
        emit StartStaked(msg.sender, _amount, block.timestamp);
    }
    
    function withdraw(uint256 _amount) external updateReward(msg.sender) {
        require( (block.timestamp - stakeStart[msg.sender]) >= initialTime, "Not time yet" ); 
        require(_balances[msg.sender] > 0, "You don't have any tokens Staked");
        require(_balances[msg.sender] >= _amount, "You don't have enought tokens in Staking");
        
        if((block.timestamp - stakeStart[msg.sender]) < lockedTime){
            uint _amountToWithdraw = _amount - (_amount / 8); // penalty 12,50%
            _totalSupply -= _amount;
            _balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
            stakingToken.transfer(msg.sender, _amountToWithdraw);
            
            emit WitdrawStaked(msg.sender, _amountToWithdraw, block.timestamp, true);
            
        }else{
            _totalSupply -= _amount;
            _balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
            stakingToken.transfer(msg.sender, _amount); // without penalty
            
            emit WitdrawStaked(msg.sender, _amount, block.timestamp, false);
            
        }
        
    }

    function getReward() external updateReward(msg.sender) {
        require( (block.timestamp - stakeStart[msg.sender]) >= initialTime, "Not time yet" ); 
        
        if((block.timestamp - stakeStart[msg.sender]) < lockedTime){
            uint reward = rewards[msg.sender] - (rewards[msg.sender] / 8); // penalty 12,50%
            rewards[msg.sender] = 0;
            rewardsToken.transfer(msg.sender, reward);
            
            emit WitdrawRewards(msg.sender, reward, block.timestamp, true);
            
        }else{
            uint reward = rewards[msg.sender];
            rewards[msg.sender] = 0;
            rewardsToken.transfer(msg.sender, reward); // without penalty
            
            emit WitdrawRewards(msg.sender, reward, block.timestamp, false);
        }
        
    }
    
    
    function changeLockedTime(uint _newLockedTime) public onlyOwner{
        lockedTime = _newLockedTime;
    }
    
    function changeInitialReward(uint _newInitialReward) public onlyOwner{
        initialTime = _newInitialReward;
    }
    
    function getStaked(address _account) external view returns(uint){
        return _balances[_account];
    }
    
    
}



interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}
```

this contract is so clean and well done, i recommand using it.

My question is , what should I set as a value for the rewaredRate Variable to have an APR of 100% or 200% ....

how can I calculate what value to use ?

thanks

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this? I'm trying to figure it out also

Comment: Depending on the chain you deployed the contract to, the average block time is a given amount of seconds. From that, you can calculate the yearly return.

Answer (score 0):

I have a contract and that value is set to uint256 public rewardRate = 2322; which is 23% and 22%

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you can not have a fixed APY for users, as the `rewardRate` is rewarded to all stakeholders.

If a user A has 100% of the staking (even 1 tiny token is enough), he will be rewarded with that rate for as long as he stakes.

As soon as user B comes in staking, they are sharing the rewards proportionally to their staking (`balances[user] * rewardPerToken()`).
Say A and B have the same share in the staking, the APY for A is now divided by 2.

Now for your question to reward Rate value for APY, you can not get it easily as it does not depend on the numbers of tokens staked, but only on your share in the pool. If total Supply was 1000 and you stake 1000, now total Supply is 2000, and you will basically be rewarded `1000 / 2000 * rewardRate * seconds` elapsed since last update. (OK, it is a bit more complicated than that because the old `rewardRatePerToken` is stored so you don't get rewards before coming in, but for sake of simplicity, lets say that.)

Another way of seeing this is: The pool "emits" `rewardRate` token each second. It will be shared among stakers.

So you will get `rewardRate * your share` each second.

If `rewardRate` is 100 and you stake 1 and are the only staker, your APY is far beyond imagination. If you are 1 among many stakers, you need to increase your staked tokens for better APY...

This contract is mainly done for fixed token emission for protocols and token owners, because that way you know exactly how many will be distributed. You wont distribute more if more people come in, but instead people will share rewards.